Using Mata function inside `nlcom`?
I'm interested in a function that does not admit a closed-form expression, so I approximate it using a Mata function.
How can I call this Mata function from nlcom?
I perfectly understand that I could calculate numerical derivatives etc. on my own, but feels a bit unnecessary given that everything is already in nlcom.

It's hard to know what you're seeking here, unless it is to clone nlcom and add custom code calling a Mata function. There isn't a handle to do what you want otherwise, IIUC,
